# How can the facet function in ggplot be used to create a histogram in order to visualize distributions for all variables in a dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

This is an example of the variables that I would like to visualize

```
id  post.test.score  pre.test.score  messages  forum.posts  av.assignment.score
1        0.37             0.48         68          7               0.19
2        0.52             0.37         83         22               0.28
3        0.42             0.37         81          7               0.25
4        0.56             0.34         94         14               0.27
5        0.25             0.39         42         11               0.07
```

Comment: Take a look again at [ask]. What have you tried? Seeing your code would be helpful to know where you're going wrong / help find SO posts that already cover this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied the data from your post above so you can skip the variable assignment

```
library("tidyverse")

df <- read.table(file = "clipboard", header = T) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

You need to modify your data structure slightly before you pass it to ggplot. Get each of your test names into a single variable with `tidyr::gather`. Then pipe to `ggplot`:

```
df %>% 
  gather(test, value, -id) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_grid(~test)
```